# What is the equivalent python statement

Tags: ironpython

These are C# staments I'd like to try with IronPython, what's the equivalent in Python?

```
using My.NameSpace;
MyType mt = new MyType();
```

TIA

Comment: That should be pretty much covered by any random tutorial for Python. Asking questions here is not a replacement for following a tutorial or reading documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
from My.NameSpace import MyType
mt = MyType()
```

Python supports modules which can be imported in other python files. So, in the first line, we're import MyType class from the My.NameSpace module. (importing just the required objects is considered as best practice in Python which keeps the namespace clean. If you want to import everything, use `from My.NameSpace import *`) 
Also, Python is a dynamically typed language and thus doesn't require type of the object. So we just create a new object using MyType and assign it to variable name mt using `mt = MyType()`

Comment: Please provide an explanation or code comment. This is a low quality post as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

```
mt = MyType()
```

in python you don't have to specify type or using new keyword